# The message of Yogi Berra's sayings

Tags: meaning, phrases

> 1. When someone asked Berra how he liked school, he said, "Closed."
> 2. Take it with a grin of salt
> 3. It gets late early out here
> 4. I think they just got through marinating the greens

These are Yogi Berra's sayings of which I can't understand the meaning.

Would you help me understand these sayings' meaning?

Comment: You should only pick one or two sayings at the most, and then explain what you think they mean. Do you not have any idea for number 1 and 3, you don't have to be a native speaker to understand those. Oh, by the way, they're not really sayings, they are jokes and puns. Nope, he's not a comedian, just Googled his name, they are  however, malapropisms.

Comment: For 1, I guess his answer was negative, but I'm not sure how he expressed his negative answer by saying "closed". I thought it is an unusual way of using the word "closed".

Comment: For 3, it sounds like a paradox but I don't get the implication of it.

Comment: For 2, maybe he treated 'it' (other's words) as a food?

Comment: Virtually all of the quotes attributed to Berra are plays on words of one sort or another.  Hint: in the first one, "like" can be used to mean "prefer".

Comment: In case you are not familiar with it, Yogi Berra’s unwittingly humorous quotes were (probably) the inspiration for [Yogi Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Bear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick look at the four quotations you ask about.

***When someone asked Berra how he liked school, he said, "Closed."***

Berra was not a scholarly guy, and he wasn't a huge fan of school. But when someone asked him how he liked school, instead of saying "Not much" or something similarly focused on what his feelings about school were, Berra interpreted the question as asking him to identify the conditions under which he liked school most. "Closed" means simply "I liked school most when it was closed." The misunderstanding of this question to comic effect is reminiscent of an anecdote in which someone asked Diogenes, the famously penniless cynic philosopher/gadfly of Athens (and other parts of Ancient Greece), what his favorite wine was. His answer: "Other people's."

***Take it with a grin of salt***

This is simply a malapropism in which Berra either misstated or misunderstood the idiomatic phrase "take it with a grain of salt" (meaning don't accept it at face value) as containing the word *grin* instead of *grain*. The fictional Mrs. Malaprop in Richard Sheridan's play *The Rivals* repeatedly commits similar errors, such as referring to a chivalrous person as "the pine-apple [instead of *pinnacle*] of politeness."

***It gets late early out here***

This a logical paradox because *late* and *early* are opposites. The idea that one happens on a schedule defined by its opposite is difficult to make sense of unless you change the terms of the statement. There are at least two ways to apply a meaningful interpretation to what Berra said. One is to imagine that he was playing a game in a city farther north than where he was used to playing, and that sundown came earlier than he expected; we could rephrase his comment more accurately in that case as, "It gets dark early up here." Another possibility is that he was visiting a city where the nightlife (bars, restaurants, clubs, etc.) shut down earlier than it did in New York; we could capture the gist of his comment in that case as "Businesses close for the night early around here."

***I think they just got through marinating the greens***

This is another malapropism. In all likelihood Berra was trying to come up with the word *irrigating* or the word *manicuring*. The joke is that *marinating*, though it falls roughly halfway between those two words, has nothing to do with golf or with golf greens.

Comment: You could  also add that to marinade something is a cooking procedure, and there's a tomato sauce called "marinara". I was a bit stuck on that one, tell the truth.

Comment: What a splendid explanation! Thank you so much! I'm so astounded by your insightfulness

Comment: Oh, _greens_ as in golf greens. I thought the last one was quite clear and unambiguous (though lacking context, of course), meaning, “I think they just finished marinating the vegetables”. Guess not!

Comment: This is a fundamentally incorrect answer with the assertions ("The misunderstanding of this question", "malapropism", "Berra either misstated or misunderstood") that Berra made these statements in error. He did not. He intentionally spoke like this for comedic effect, much like Johan Cruyff. It unfortunately makes this explanation far off the mark. These quotes, and others like them from Berra are actually quite brilliant and funny ("When you get to a fork in the road... take it").

Comment: For an instance of the fork remark from August 2, 1913 (12 years before Yogi Berra was born), see "[Wise Directions](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88064430/1913-08-02/ed-1/seq-7/#words=%22fork+in+the+road+take+it%22)" in the _Madison [Louisiana] Journal_: "When you come to a fork in the road, take it." "I will, if it is a silver one." The same joke also appears in the _Abbeville [Louisiana] Progress_ (August 2, 1913) and the _Hays [Kansas] Free Press_ (August 23, 1913). Likewise, the famous Yogi-ism, "Nobody goes there any more. It's too crowded" appeared in _The New Yorker_ ...

Comment: ... (February 10, 1943) in one of John McNulty’s [Third Avenue sketches](https://books.google.com/books?id=S9RLAAAAIAAJ&q=%22too+crowded%22+McNulty&dq=%22too+crowded%22+McNulty&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd_9Df9KTaAhWKGnwKHfJTAxc4ChDoAQgzMAI), three years before Berra’s major league debut with the Yankees. And two years before that, the _Helena [Montana] Independent_  (September 10, 1941) mentioned a young woman saying, “Now I know why nobody ever comes here; it’s too crowded,” according to _The [Yale] Dictionary of Quotations_ (2006). ...

Comment: ... As for the “it gets late early” quip, it has antecedents going back at least to 1871. From the [_Daily Wabash Express_](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=DWE18711106.1.4&txq=%22gets+late+early%22) (November 6, 1871): “The days are shortening and the nights are lengthening. It gets late early now.” The same amusing juxtaposition of “late” and “early” in the phrase “it gets late early” also appears in newspapers from Terre-Haute, Indiana (1871); Richmond, Indiana (1871); Holmes County, Ohio (1872); Pueblo, Colorado (1885); Spanish Fork, Utah (1907); ...

Comment: ... St Tammany, Louisiana (1908); Tensas, Louisiana (1908); Omaha, Nebraska (1910); Hartford, Kentucky (1910); Washington, D.C. (1910); Phoenix, Arizona (1910); New York City (1920); Hammond, Indiana (1921); and San Bernardino, California (1923). Yogi Berra may have lit up the world with playful wit and profound insight—or he may have been credited with a potpourri of recycled gags and older-than-vaudeville wordplay that he had nothing to do with. No doubt he said some amusing things—intentionally or not—and yet, as he may never actually have said, “I never said half the things I said.”

Comment: @SvenYargs, after further research and your excellent additional comments, I stand corrected on my assertion that Berra *always* intentionally said what he said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> It gets late early out there

This Yogi-ism is actually a brilliant perspective on how quickly baseball games and seasons can get away from a team, but Yogi originally was referencing the long shadows that begin to stretch across an outfield well before sundown.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand is that Yogi Berra was not a wise man, of the sort who is quoted because the things he said were so clever. He is  quoted because he often made mistakes in speaking, and those mistakes were often humorous. For example, there is an English expression "to take with a grain of salt" that means to not take something too seriously. Berra has simply said it wrong here; there is no deeper meaning than that.